# Wordpress + Divi theme: control excerpt length based on category?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a category called 'News'. The category ID is '20'. I am using the Divi (Divi child) theme + Wordpress and want to shorten the excerpt for the News category.

I typically would use the 'add_filter' function like this:

```
<pre>
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'news_excerpt_length');
function news_excerpt_length($length) {
    if(in_category(20)) {
        return 30;
    } else {
        return 60;
    }
}
</pre>
```

But that ain't workin'. I found the excerpt control in the 'main-modules.php' and figure to add my filter here? Has anyone done this?

I added the 'main-module.php' to the root of my child theme and then added this to my child 'functions.php'

```
<pre>
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_builder_add_main_elements' ) ) :
function et_builder_add_main_elements() {
require ET_BUILDER_DIR . 'main-structure-elements.php';
require 'main-modules.php';
do_action( 'et_builder_ready' );
}
endif;
</pre>
```

It didn't break the theme, but it didn't work either. Does anyone have any experience with this particular issue?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To override the post_excerpt lengh, you can find in `custom_functions.php` the function `truncate_post()`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'truncate_post' ) ) {

    function truncate_post( $amount, $echo = true, $post = '', $strip_shortcodes = false ) {
        global $shortname;

        if ( '' == $post ) global $post;

        $post_excerpt = '';
        $post_excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );

        if ( 'on' == et_get_option( $shortname . '_use_excerpt' ) && '' != $post_excerpt ) {
            if ( $echo ) echo $post_excerpt;
            else return $post_excerpt;
        } else {
            // get the post content
            $truncate = $post->post_content;

            // remove caption shortcode from the post content
            $truncate = preg_replace( '@\[caption[^\]]*?\].*?\[\/caption]@si', '', $truncate );

            // remove post nav shortcode from the post content
            $truncate = preg_replace( '@\[et_pb_post_nav[^\]]*?\].*?\[\/et_pb_post_nav]@si', '', $truncate );

            // Remove audio shortcode from post content to prevent unwanted audio file on the excerpt
            // due to unparsed audio shortcode
            $truncate = preg_replace( '@\[audio[^\]]*?\].*?\[\/audio]@si', '', $truncate );

            if ( $strip_shortcodes ) {
                $truncate = et_strip_shortcodes( $truncate );
            } else {
            // apply content filters
                $truncate = apply_filters( 'the_content', $truncate );
            }

            // decide if we need to append dots at the end of the string
            if ( strlen( $truncate ) <= $amount ) {
                $echo_out = '';
            } else {
                $echo_out = '...';
                // $amount = $amount - 3;
            }

            // trim text to a certain number of characters, also remove spaces from the end of a string ( space counts as a character )
            $truncate = rtrim( et_wp_trim_words( $truncate, $amount, '' ) );

            // remove the last word to make sure we display all words correctly
            if ( '' != $echo_out ) {
                $new_words_array = (array) explode( ' ', $truncate );
                array_pop( $new_words_array );

                $truncate = implode( ' ', $new_words_array );

                // append dots to the end of the string
                $truncate .= $echo_out;
            }

            if ( $echo ) echo $truncate;
            else return $truncate;
        };
    }


}
```

You don't need to put `if ( ! function_exists( 'truncate_post' ) ) {` to make it work just create your function with the same name in functions.php

If you are using a child theme (I really hope so with a theme like this), copy/paste index.php and paste these lines, line 54

```
if(in_category(20)) {
    truncate_post( 30 );
} else {
    truncate_post( 60 );
}
```

It can be easier

Hope it helps

Comment: Last solution is easier to maintain. Less coding. Hope they will change this file is future update...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it ( although I don't know which solution is better ) by putting this in my 'main-module.php' starting on line 12319

```
                    // do not display the content if it contains Blog, Post Slider, Fullwidth Post Slider, or Portfolio modules to avoid infinite loops
                    if ( ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_blog' ) && ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_portfolio' ) && ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_post_slider' ) && ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_fullwidth_post_slider' ) ) {
                        if ( 'on' === $show_content ) {
                            global $more;

                            // page builder doesn't support more tag, so display the_content() in case of post made with page builder
                            if ( et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used( get_the_ID() ) ) {
                                $more = 1;
                                the_content();
                            } else {
                                $more = null;
                                the_content( esc_html__( 'read more...', 'et_builder' ) );
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ( has_excerpt() ) {
                                the_excerpt();
                            } else {
                                if(in_category(20)) {
                                  echo wpautop( truncate_post( 70, false ) );
                           } else {
                          echo wpautop( truncate_post( 370, false ) );
                          }

                            }
                        }
                    } else if ( has_excerpt() ) {
                        the_excerpt();
                    }
```